# Converting unicode fraction characters (vulgar fractions) to decimals in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm trying to convert the following text to a decimal number in excel 2003:

"93⅛"

The output should be: 93.125

I've gotten this to work with ¼, ½, ¾ by using the Replace function in VBA:
For example, this works:

```
cur_cell = Replace(cur_cell, "½", " 1/2")
```

However, the ⅛ and family characters are not supported in the VBA editor. They display as ??. Instead, I tried to replace the unicode value directly:

```
cur_cell = Replace(cur_cell, " & ChrW$(&H215B) & ", " 1/8")
```

But this doesn't work.

Is there a good way to convert these strings to numbers that I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
cur_cell = Replace(cur_cell, ChrW$(&H215B), " 1/8")
```

Your example was saying: replace the string consisting of a space, an ampersand, a space [etc.] with `1/8`. Clearly that's not what you want to do!

I'd actually recommend:

```
cur_cell.Value = Replace(Replace(cur_cell.Value, ChrW$(&H215B), ".125")," ","")
```

to circumvent Excel's automatic replacement of fractions. I just don't like to rely on that kind of automatic stuff. Why not write it as a decimal number straight off? Also, I like explicitly refering to the cell's `.Value` property as opposed to relying on it being the default property.

Comment: This worked. Quoting the ChrW() in my original example was my mistake.

Comment: I totally agree - explicity is great. Nice solution! +1